# Apache2 virtual host missing Document Root

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, a-records

thank you in advance.

I just following a tutorial from digitalocean : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts .
I completed all instruction but when I start to test the configuration and add an A Record from my parking domain, let say example.com and my digitalocean vps address is 192.168.10.2. 
In this schenario I add these 3 virtual host with 3 different DocumentRoot:

1. /var/www/domainone.example.com/index.html
2. /var/www/domaintwo.example.com/index.html
3. /var/www/domainthree.example.com/index.html

Then in my parking domain I add 3 different A record as below :

1. name : domainone.example.com address : 192.168.10.2
2. name : domaintwo.example.com address : 192.168.10.2
3. name : domainthree.example.com address : 192.168.10.2

When I execute, it happens as follow :

1. URL **domainone.example.com** goes to /var/www/**domainone.example.com**/index.html
2. URL **domaintwo.example.com** goes to /var/www/**domaintwo.example.com**/index.html
3. but this URL ***domainthree.example.com*** goes to /var/www/***domaintwo.example.com***/index.html

I am sure that I wrote a correct documentRoot at /etc/apache2/sites-available/(for each domain).config and restart the apache2 service

Thank you again

**Edit**

1. This is for /etc/apache2/sites-available/domaintwo.example.com.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
       # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
       # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
       # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
       # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
       # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
       # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
       #ServerName www.example.com

       ServerAdmin localhost@admin
       DocumentRoot /var/www/domaintwo.example.com/public
       ServerName domaintwo.example.com
       ServerAlias www.domaintwo.example.com

       # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
       # error, crit, alert, emerg.
       # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
       # modules, e.g.
       #LogLevel info ssl:warn

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
       # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
       # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
       # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
       # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
       #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
       SSLEngine on
   ```

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
2. This is for /etc/apache2/sites-available/domainthree.example.com.conf

   ```
       <VirtualHost *:80>
       # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
       # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
       # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
       # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
       # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
       # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
       # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
       #ServerName www.example.com

       ServerAdmin localhost@admin
       DocumentRoot /var/www/domainthree.example.com/public
       ServerName domainthree.example.com
       ServerAlias www.domainthree.example.com

       # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
       # error, crit, alert, emerg.
       # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
       # modules, e.g.
       #LogLevel info ssl:warn

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
       # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
       # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
       # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
       # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
       #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
       </VirtualHost>
   ```

Comment: Can we have your `Apache` configuration file for the VirtualHosts?

Comment: @D4V1D I just add the configuration file for virtualhost, please take a look :)

Comment: Why there isn't **domainone** VirtualHost conf file?

Comment: Can you verify in the output of `sudo apache2ctl -S` whether everything is enabled as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It's a SSL issue IMO. Domain 2 is alphabetically sorted higher then 3 (priority). Apache executes domaintwo as default via HTTPS (SSL). So the VH for domain 3 is wrong or not enabled for both protocols.
I'm guessing more or less. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have the same results with both protocols? (HTTPS/HTTP)